# Heat equation solution does not apparently satisfy initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The problem statement is-

> A rod has its $x=0$ end at $0^\circ C$ and the $x=l$ end at $100^\circ C$. Now at $t>0$, we keep $x=0=l$ at $0^\circ C$. The time dependent heat equation solution is $$u=\frac{200}{\pi}\sum\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}e^{-(n\pi\alpha/l)^2t}\sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}$$

Clearly, putting $t=0$ and $x=l$ should give $100^\circ C$ as given but putting $x=l$ gives $\sin(n\pi)=0$, hence the whole thing goes to $0$ instead of $100$.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

A partial differential equation (PDE) is only well defined if the initial conditions (IC) and boundary conditions (BC) are compatible to each other on the whole spacetime domain $\Omega = [0,t]\times[x_a,x_b]$.

So in your case the problem (or your thinking) **is not well defined**.

As a hint answer the following question: Which condition has priority at $t=0$?

- The initial condition or
- the boundary condition?

By the way, you have not even stated the initial condition.

Regards

Comment: Those are exactly the conditions given in the book

Comment: Anyway, summarizing your confusion: The initial condition at $x=l$ is $u=0$ and not $u=100$. Otherwise the problem is not well defined.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but the problem statement says, $x=l$ is at $100^\circ C$ at $t=0$.

Comment: @tatan I think this sentence is misleading or simply wrong. There are only two possibilies: Either your IC is $u=0$ at $x=l$ and your given solution holds for $t\ge 0$, or your IC is $u=100$ at $x=l$ and your given solution only holds for $t > 0$.